# Relacionamento 1:N mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Estou criando uma aplicação de streaming semelhante a netflix e gostaria de saber qual seria a
melhor forma de tratar os "relacionamentos" no mongo.(Não sei se usar um banco noSQL é a melhor opção, mas não me importo, é somente por questões de estudos mesmo...nada profissional).

Quando se trata de postar filmes é tranquilo.Bastaria criar em um model, mas se tratando de séries(breaking bad,friends etc.) qual seria a melhor maneira? já que uma série possui vários episódios e estes por sua vez provavelmente terão que possuir um ID pra toda vez que o usuário clicar em um deles ser redirecionado para a guia com o ID daquele episódio.
Minha dúvida é a seguinte:  é melhor criar um MODEL novo para cada episódio postado(creio eu que não seja a melhor maneira, já que dessa forma acabaria tendo vários models e caso fosse uma aplicação grande se tornaria inviável). Ou o ideal é ter um campo do tipo Array dentro do model de cada série postada?
Exemplo:

```
serieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
episodes: Array
)}
```

desta forma eu vejo mais sentido, porém não consigo pensar em como eu passaria um ID para cada novo episódio postado.Me desculpem se ficou confuso, agradeço quem puder me dar uma ajuda com o raciocínio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa! Bem, não tenho uma ideia exata sobre como você está pensando a modelagem mas de acordo com o pessoal do MongoDB* a recomendação para os relacionamentos 1:N é embutir ao invés de referenciar, ou seja, colocar a parte do N dentro do 1, algo como:

```js
{
  __id:...,
  title: "Nome da Série",
  year: 1999,
  mainCast: [ ... ],
  totalSeasons: 9,
  totalEpisodes: 9,
  ...
  episodeList: {
    1: {
      season: 1,
      cast: [ ... ],
      ...
}}}
```

A exceção desta regra são as relações 1:Z (1 para zilhões, do pessoal de Big Data).

(*) A fonte é o curso [M320 - Data Modeling](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M320/about) da MongoDB University que apresenta padrões de projeto para a modelagem das bases de dados. Aliás, o curso é gratuito.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda e por fornecer a fonte :)